# Wordpress simple rewrite rule not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule in Wordpress to create direct pretty links to search results.

I'm working with a custom post type called 'object'

My result page is located at this url : http://www.domain.com/objects/

I want to create this kind of URL to point a listing of new objects : http://www.domain.com/objects/new

The rewritten query must be : http://www.domain.com/objects/?filter=new

I will then be able to use the $_GET['filter'] value to query my objects (meta_query)...

**my problem**

I've try to to this with this code:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%filter%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('objects/new/','objects/?filter=new','top');
```

.htaccess looks then like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^objects/new/ /objects/?filter=new [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Unfortunately, when I try to reach the URL *http://www.domain.com/objects/new* I've got a 404 error :(

Debug bar show me this:

```
Request:
   objects/new

Query String:
   attachment=new

Matched Rewrite Rule:
   [^/]+/([^/]+)/?$

Matched Rewrite Query:
   attachment=new
```

Can someone tell me why Wordpress try to retrieve an attachment? 
Is something wrong in my rewrite rule or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Few Questions 
1. is this working properly - http://www.domain.com/objects/
2. http://www.domain.com/objects/filter/new - whether it will be ok for you ?

Comment: Hi Pramod, I don't understand what you mean with these questions? domain.com/objects is an existing WP page, and domain.com/objects/filter/new is not a good solution for me since I don't want the "filter" in the final url (I want domain.com/objects/new)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK,
I've finnaly found a way to achieve this.

Here is the code I added to my theme:

```
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        'objects/(.+)'  =>  'index.php?page_id=27&filtre=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

where 27 is the Wordpress ID of the "/objects" page I want to reach with the rewritten URL, and:

```
function custom_wp_querystring() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%filtre%','([^&]+)');
}
```

In order to tell Wordpress I need to use a custom query var called "filtre".

This last function must be added on init action:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_wp_querystring');
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

Important thing to know, in my page template (the one with ID 27 in my example), if I want to test the query var, it's not possible to do that kind of test:

```
if ( isset ( $_GET['filtre'] ) ) { ... }
```

GET vars are 'hidden' due to Wordpress redirection, you must then do:

```
if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['filtre'] ) ) { ... }
```

Comment: You are adding the rule by coding while plugin add the code direltly on db..:)

Comment: Thanks, was using a rule with `index.php?pagename=some-page-name` without luck, by using `index.php?page_id=123` all is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugin [Rewrite plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/screenshots/) it will help you to analysize which rule is working when you hit the url..you can create new rewrite rule and can check here itself whether they are working accordingly or not.

There is no need to write anything in wordpress because wordpress itself has a wp_rewrite class which manages all the rewrite rules.

Try with several rewrite rules and set the rule priority accordingly. because the rule mentioned or listed above in the list will match first if a match found above then wordpress will ignore the below listed rules.

I have used this plugin and its work for me the way i want. Attaching the screenshot here

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks! This plugin seems nice but I've never found how to delete added rules :( I use Debug Bar to see analyze queries. Unfortunately, my problem is not that one, I know how to add rewrite rules, I simply don't know the right way to construct rules to achieve what I want :S

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule needs to be placed as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^objects/new(.*)$ /objects/?filter=new [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi, even with this rule above wordpress regular rules, Wordpress is querying an 'attachement'